# Why does my TPL program use more ThreadPool resources than its async/await counterpart?

Tags: .net, io, task-parallel-library, async-await, threadpool

I am writing a program that demonstrates the benefits of using asynchronous IO in the context of server scalability.  The program concurrently consumes an asynchronous method, and then reports the IDs of the threads that participated in the asynchronous processing.

To illustrate, consider the following:

```
static async Task<TimeSpan> AsyncCalling(TimeSpan time)
{
    using (SleepService.SleepServiceClient client = new SleepService.SleepServiceClient())
    {
        TimeSpan response = await client.SleepAsync(time);
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        response += await client.SleepAsync(TimeSpan.FromTicks(time.Ticks / 2));
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        return response;
    }
}
```

I simulate a server under load by calling the above async method as follows:

```
int numberOfWorkItems = 50;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkItems; ++i)
{
    TimeSpan value = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((i % 3) + 1);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(arg => { TimeSpan t = AsyncCalling(value).Result; });

    Thread.Sleep(300);
}
```

The `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` operation simulates the allocation of a request thread, with the `AsyncCalling` method being the method executed by the request (similar to the operation of WCF).

Execution is as expected, and I only count two or three distinct thread IDs when analyzing the output.  This is typical for my machine as I only have two cores and the thread pool will resist scheduling more threads than cores available.

Now I attempt to do the same analysis, but for a TPL function that doesn't use the `await` keyword.  The function is as follows:

```
static Task<TimeSpan> TaskAsyncCalling(TimeSpan time)
{
    SleepService.SleepServiceClient client = new SleepService.SleepServiceClient();

    return client.SleepAsync(time)
                 .ContinueWith(t =>
                 {
                     TimeSpan result = t.Result;
                     Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                     return client.SleepAsync(TimeSpan.FromTicks(time.Ticks / 2))
                                  .ContinueWith(t1 =>
                                  {
                                      result += t1.Result;
                                      Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                                      (client as IDisposable).Dispose();

                                      return result;
                                  });
                 })
                 .Unwrap();
}
```

When `TaskAsyncCalling` is called in the same context, the output results are completely different.  The tasks generally take much longer to execute, and total number of unique thread IDs is generally on the order of 30 (again, for my 2-core machine).

Why does this disparity exist?  I understand that `await` is not a trivial wrapper over `Task<T>`, however the thread pool is the common denominator and I expected the same clever thread reuse to occur in the TPL implementation.

Is there another way to rewrite the TPL method to achieve the same results without blocking?

---

Edit:

The `SleepAsync` call is the asynchronous generated WCF client method for the following synchronous operation.  Note that in this case, the client does not block where as the server does.

```
public TimeSpan Sleep(TimeSpan time)
{
    Thread.Sleep(time);
    return time;
}
```

Comment: What is the execution environment of this test (a console app, ASP.NET, etc)? Also, what does `SleepAsync` look like?

Comment: This is a console application, and SleepAsync is the generated async client method for a trivial WCF Sleep operation (it calls Thread.Sleep).

Comment: Besides `Thread.Sleep`, do you use `await` inside `SleepAsync`, as the method is apparently `async`? It'd help if you showed its code.

Comment: It does not use `await` -- see edit above.

Comment: Odd -- I should also note that if I replace the async WCF call with a local method that calls `await Task.Delay(time); return time;`, then I see the high-thread ID count in BOTH implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the classic TPL version uses more threads than the `async/await` version because each `ContinueWith` continuation is executed on a separate pool thread.

Fix that with `TaskContinuationsOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`:

```
static Task<TimeSpan> TaskAsyncCalling(TimeSpan time)
{
    SleepService.SleepServiceClient client = new SleepService.SleepServiceClient();

    return client.SleepAsync(time)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            TimeSpan result = t.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            return client.SleepAsync(TimeSpan.FromTicks(time.Ticks / 2))
                .ContinueWith(t1 =>
                {
                    result += t1.Result;
                    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    (client as IDisposable).Dispose();

                    return result;
                }, TaskContinuationsOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
         }, TaskContinuationsOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
         .Unwrap();
 }
```

OTOH, the `await` continuations are normally executed synchronously (if the operation completed on the same synchronization context it was started on, or if there was no synchronization at both points of execution). So it's expected to acquire two less threads.

A good related read: ["Why is TaskContinuationsOptions.ExecuteSynchronously opt-in?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/05/24/10014209.aspx)

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks for figuring this out and giving the reference information.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the two implementations are the same, `await` stores the current 
`SyncrhonizationContext` and gets the TaskScheduler associated with that. Which is not what the default implementation of `ContinueWith` does. From reflector:

```
public Task ContinueWith(Action<Task<TResult>> continuationAction)
{
    StackCrawlMark lookForMyCaller = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
    return this.ContinueWith(continuationAction, TaskScheduler.Current, new CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.None, ref lookForMyCaller);
}
```

So `ContinueWith` uses the `TaskScheduler.Current` whereas `await` uses the `TaskScheduler` associated with the current `SyncrhonizationContext`. If the two are not the same you may get different behavior.

Try specifying a `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` for `ContinueWith` and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Reference source for the `Task` class: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs.html

Comment: Calling `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` in my console application throws an exception stating that the context may not be used as a scheduler.

Comment: Digging a bit more -- if I inspect the static `TaskScheduler.Current` after `await client.SleepAsync()` is signaled, it shows that the await implementation references the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`.  This is also the default, which is used in TPL implementation.

Comment: Interesting, I see from your comment that if you replace the WCF call with a local method call both versions run the same. Might be worth examining them in a profiler like [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to see where the time is spent.